# MySQL query about union

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table A
=======
Name  |  Qty
------------
AA    |  1
BB    |  2
CC    |  3
DD    |  4


table B
=======
Name  |  Qty
------------
AA    |  0
BB    |  0
EE    |  0
ZZ    |  0
```

and i need this as resoult

```
Name  |  Qty
------------
AA    |  1
BB    |  2
CC    |  3
DD    |  4
EE    |  0
ZZ    |  0
```

how to do it ? i try with union but not get the resault

Comment: How do you decide which qty you want to show in the result?

Comment: You need to clarify what the second table is. Is it just the first table, followed by the second table, and if the data is in both tables the first table takes priority?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a prioritization query, where you want the records from `a` and if not present there, then from `b`.  Here is one method:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.name = b.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want union to merge the totals.

```
 SELECT Name, SUM(Qty)
 FROM (
      SELECT Name, Qty
      FROM TableA
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT Name, Qty
      FROM TableB
      ) T
GROUP BY Name
```

Make sure use `UNION ALL` so you dont lose duplicate rows.